# Area of convex n-gon using triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Suppose we have a convex $n$-gon and a point inside the $n$-gon or on the sides of the $n$-gon, and suppose one extended lines from all the vertices of the $n$-gon to make $n$ triangles with two of its vertices on the $n$-gon and the third vertex being the point itself. Is there a nice formula for the sum of the areas of alternating triangles? Is there a nice point such that the two different area values mentioned above are equivalent?

Comment: Um, I don't think so.  The sum of the areas of all the triangles will equal the area of the whole polygon and as the polygon need not be regular so there is no way to determine the area.

Comment: I added on another question. The second part has some nice points with a regular n-gon, but I want to see a proof of all possible points. I have an outline of a proof for a regular n-gon, but not for a non regular n-gon.

Comment: What's "alternating" here? And which are "the two different area values mentioned above"? I only see one, "the sum of the areas of alternating triangles". Is this referring to "area of convex $n$-gon" in the title?

Comment: By that, I meant that if you took the triangles, and went clockwise, and alternated triangles and took the sum of those areas (area 1=triangle 1+triangle 3+triangle 5+..., area2=triangle2+triangle4+triangle6+...).

Comment: For $n=4$, there is such a point: Start in one corner, where two of the triangles are degenerate and the other two are formed by the diagonal incident at that corner. Then move to the opposite corner, where the same situation obtains, but with the triangles switched. Thus the difference has changed sign, and since it's a continuous function of the point, by the intermediate value theorem it must have been zero at some point.

Comment: Your "alternating triangles" are undefined for odd $n$.

Comment: For even $n$, you can move one vertex while keeping all others fixed and the total area constant, so that the even and odd sums are unrelated.

Comment: Could you clarify on your above comment?

Comment: I am not able to derive the required formula. However, I have the special case for the 2m-gon being a regular one solved. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485516/total-areas-of-alternating-subtriangles-in-a-regular-2n-gon/1487676#1487676

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your point is $(x,y)$, and the vertices are $(x_1,y_1)\dots(x_n,y_n)$. Then the area of the *first* triangle is ${1\over2}\Big((x-x_1)(y-y_2)-(x-x_2)(y-y_1)\Big)$, which is in fact a **linear** function of $(x,y)$. A sum of several linear functions is again a linear function. So the problem in question basically means that we solve a single linear equation. Depending on the coefficients, the answer might be the whole plane (which, I believe, is the case for a regular even-sided n-gon), one particular line, or an empty set.

**Upd.** Come to think of it, all three situations are possible. The example of the first one is a regular square. The second occurs in a non-regular quadrangle, as explained by @joriki's comment. The third takes place in a hexagon with side lengths 1, 100, 1, 100, 1, 100 (in that order).

Comment: This makes sense, nice explanation. I am now curious however; all of these options give many points, or no points. Is there a case where it gives only one point?

Comment: I don't think so. There are no other options. How can a single linear equation in 2 variables have a single point for a solution? It can't.