# Total Areas of Alternating Subtriangles in a regular 2n-gon

Tags: geometry

I came across [this cool interactive graphic](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/~alfred/jsxgui/JSXGraph.git/examples/alternating_subtriangles.html) a few days ago that essentially demonstrates the fact that the areas of alternating subtriangles in a regular 2n-gon are the same. Quoting from that page,

> Let P be a point connected to and inside the vertices of a [regular] 2n-gon. Number the triangles in order from 1 to 2n. Then the sum of the areas of the even-numbered triangles is equal to the sum of the areas of the odd-numbered triangles.

However, while the page demonstrates it to be numerically true, it does not offer a geometric proof of this fact.

I believe that the proof could involve the [shoelace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), which would allow you to find the signed area of each of the segments. However, when I tried writing out a series notation version for the odd and even triangles, I could not get terms to cancel.

Is there a more elegant way other than just setting up coordinates for each point (which didn't seem to work when I tried it anyway).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464949.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient for me to use a regular octagon as an example.

[image]

Fact-1) $⊿3$ is on the diametrically opposite side of $⊿7$. Similarly, ($⊿1$ and $⊿5$) form another pair. Other pairs can be similarly found.

Fact-2) $h_3$ is the altitude of $⊿3$. The others are defined similarly.

Fact-3) $XPY$ is a straight line and $XP + PY = L$, which is a $n$ and radius related constant. Similar lines can be found with that length.

Fact-4) $([⊿1] + [⊿5]) + ([⊿3] + [⊿7]) = \dfrac {S.[(h_1 + h_5) + (h_3 + h_7)]}{2} = SL$. This sum will be the same for the even numbered sub-triangles

Comment: This proof doesn't work for odd $n$. Instead consider the polygon obtained by extending the edges of the even (odd) edges. The subtriangles in these two $n$-gons fill the same area, and they are a fixed fraction larger than the subtriangles of the original polygon (having the same height, but a wider base).

Comment: @TomVerhoeff You are right about the 1st sentence. However, the OP is looking for solution about an "2n-gon".

Comment: Yes, indeed, and I was referring to the $n$ in $2n$ being odd. So, for instance, your proof does not work for $n=3$, that is, for 6-gons, because opposite triangles then belong to _different_ parts of the bipartition.

Comment: @TomVerhoeff No. The "2n" should be treated as a whole and therefore should be interpreted as an even number.

Answer (score 1):

The claim clearly holds if the point lies on a vertex. Since the areas are linear functions of the coordinates of the point as long as the point doesn't cross an edge, and the affine span of the vertices is the entire plane, the claim holds in the entire interior of the polygon.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am still interested in a proof for regular polygons though and as such have edited the question.

Comment: @1110101001 At one time, I dare not to answer your question until you have rephrased it with the condition – “regular’ added in. It is unfortunate to see that important condition was never shown in the original related link. That misled me to think that is true for all (irregular) 2m-gons.

Comment: @Mick: See the edit history of my answer for a short proof that the original claim without "regular" was false.

Comment: Your edit history is not retrace-able but your support is appreciated.

Comment: @Mick: Not my edit history, that of my answer. You can get it by clicking on "edited X days ago".

Comment: Last time when I clicked that it gave me a server error. Got it this time.